# Not able to access deployment from external network kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, minikube, kubernetes-nodeport

I am new to Kubernetes and have a limited understanding of the Kubernetes networking part.
problem context:

- Minikube installed on VM (RHEL 8) [minikube start --driver=docker]
- under minikube node have a deployment with the service (type: nodePort) with port mapping as 8008:30000
  (refer to [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RDOY.png))

so now the confusion is I am able to access the application (in deployment) using curl < node-ip>:< node-port> inside the VM (x.y.z.w), but while trying to access from my external network, using URL as x.y.z.w:30000, I am not able to, what am I missing here?

or do I need to use ingress (with Nginx) here?

Comment: can u check your Minikube ip? `minikube service hello-minikube --url` and then try with that <ip>:<node-port>

Comment: that's exactly what I am using and am able to access from VM, but not from the external network. My understanding is I need to map host (where minikube is installed) port 30000 to nodeIP:<nodePort:30000>

Comment: can you check if the ports are open so that external request could reach the vm ?Also please check the firewall if its a cloud resource

Comment: The port is open and I am able to ping the VM from the external network as well.